# Find date range available in my sql table

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-range

I have Two Input One is

```
<input type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" class="datepicker span11" name="start_date" placeholder="Check-In Date" />
```

Second is

```
<input type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" class="datepicker span11" name="end_date" placeholder="Check-Out Date" />
```

Now The My database have two Column which is " id, start_date, end_date"
and Respectively value of them is "1, 14-05-2016, 21-05-2016"

Now when i choose Form Input box  "15-05-2016" as start_date  And "17-05-2016" as end_date. then i get empty result. 
i Checked the query in sql it is shown ok. 
then i dump this query which shows "SELECT * FROM room_inventory WHERE start_date >= '15-05-2016' AND end_date <= '17-05-2016' "

No error came. but also don't get any result.

I tried this

```
 $start_date = $_POST['start_date'];
 $end_date = $_POST['end_date'];

 $checkAvailability = "SELECT * FROM room_inventory WHERE start_date >= '$start_date' AND end_date <= '$end_date' ";

 $resultAvailability = mysqli_query($con, $checkAvailability);
 $rowAvailability = mysqli_fetch_array($resultAvailability);
 rint_r($rowAvailability);
```

So how do i get that the input date are available in this database.

Comment: @jiml  Not duplicate sir, i have  to find that my form data are available in database date range or not...  may you don't understand what i want to say.

Comment: What error or query output are you getting?

Comment: @jiml sir. in that question they have only one date column in database so it's easy to find. but i have two date columns so i don't know how to find date between them.

Comment: It would be nice to see column names and at least one row in that database. Also, you can check how that string looks like (with print("SELECT rc_type ....")) to see if there are any grammar mistakes.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I get Empty Data. i tried this query in mysql that show empty table. and there is no error show up sir.

Comment: I agree with what others have said.  You should show us some sample data and the raw query.  The empty result set may be correct for all we know.

Comment: sir actually i have some data in my table .
 SELECT * FROM room_inventory WHERE start_date >= '15-05-2016' AND end_date <= '18-05-2016';

Comment: Like start date is 1 end date is 10 what if i have two date 3 as a start and 6 as end. so can i find that 3 & 6 are between 1 & 10.

Comment: @EdvinTenovim   I fond the answer ..  and the query is 

"$sql = "SELECT start_date, end_date FROM room_inventory WHERE '$start_date' AND '$end_date' between '$start_date' and '$end_date'";'

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I fond the answer ..  and the query is 

"$sql = "SELECT start_date, end_date FROM room_inventory WHERE '$start_date' AND '$end_date' between '$start_date' and '$end_date'";'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think problem in query ...you can check by printing query text 
i think it should be :`"SELECT rc_type FROM room_inventory WHERE start_date >= ".$start_date." AND end_date <= ".$end_date ."`
i wish it will help you :)

Comment: no sql query is correct i checked in mysql

Comment: Like start date is 1 end date is 10 what if i have two date 3 as a start and 6 as end. so can i find that 3 & 6 are between 1 & 10.